# CSS folder Issue

Tags: css

i have a stupid question,
I want to load background image with the `background-image: url(images/background.jpg);` function but css file location is css/main.css.

how to do that?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Go up your folder structure. `../images/background.png`.

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoDela +1

Comment: If your question was stupid like you said, why did you ask it in the first place? Why didn't you just search it up? I'm pretty sure there are plenty of resources that have an answer to this question. Only ask questions that have never been asked or answered on some other website including stackoverflow before. Please visit stackoverflows page on how to write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @StigCoder04 This question can help to many people now, question is maybe stupid but useful.

Comment: @NiKoLaPrO, you have a point, but most people will go to w3schools instead of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-image: url("../images/background");
```

`../` puts you one folder back, if for some reason, you would need to go two, use `../../`

Also make sure to include extension (jpg/png) of the background image.